# Fiddlerroot.cer not install in bluestacks

Tags: android, bluestacks

Did anyone experience this issue before?? My fiddlerroot.cer is unable to be installed in bluestacks but is able to install in other android emulators such as genymotion

Comment: check [this](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/configure-fiddler/tasks/ConfigureForAndroid)  and [image](http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/images/ConfigureForAndroid/InstallFromStorage.png)

Comment: @maveň tried but it doesnt work as it does not have this setting

Comment: @maveň the question is about Bleustaacks not a random device  , even random device with fiddler as proxy => some application block the proxy using  , so fiddler wont handle any 80/443 ports, best way is rooting bleustacks and install fiddler's certeficats then redirect ports with proxycap , here all the apps will be forced to use fiddler as proxy ,

Comment: @K3rnel31 this sounds nice to me :)